# ASP.NET DataGrid Select ItemTemplate By Condition

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, .net-4.0

This is My DataGrid:

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="dgAll" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drdL" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetComboData(Eval("Value"))%>'></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

As you see I have a TextBox and a DropDownList, But I need just one of them in each row, So the question is how can I select ItemTemplate by condition, assume if `Eval("Type") == "TextBox")` I need TextBox and if `Eval("Type") == "DropDown")` I need DropDown in that Row. Does any one have any idea about this?

Comment: You can use a single template field and hide show control according to condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both the controls in the same template field and use code as below

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgAll" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>'
                      Visible ='<%# Eval("Type").ToString()=="TextBox"%'>
                 </asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="drdL" runat="server" 
                      DataSource='<%#GetComboData(Eval("Value"))%>'
                      Visible ='<%# Eval("Type").ToString()!="TextBox"%'>
                 </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, Just an update: I thisnk Visible instead of Visibility.

Answer (score 0):

why do you use couple asp:TemplateColumn, you can use too like that,

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="drdL" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

and in the Grid's ItemDataBound event

```
protected void dgAll_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex == -1) return;

            if (e.Item.ItemIndex % 2 == 0)
                e.Item.FindControl("drdL").Visible = true;
            else
                e.Item.FindControl("txtB").Visible = true;
        }
```